# Magento 2 : How to set secure cookie OR HTTP ONLY FLAG SET

Tags: magento2, cookie, secure

As per my security checking and testing in Magento 2, I see that secure cookie or HTTP only flag not set on the Magento 2.

For the security reason, we need the cookie to be secure. Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: have you configure Cookies from admin ?

Comment: Yes, I have configured all the required configuration related to the cookie.

Answer (score 1):

**Go to**

> Stores > Configuration > (General) > Web > Default Cookie Settings

[image]

**Cookie Lifetime.** It’s how long Cookie files stay on user’s computer. By default it’s set as 3600 seconds which is equal to about 1 hour. If you want to ensure that cookies expire when a user closes their browser, then select 0 here.

**Cookie Path.** To make cookies available for some particular folders, enter the Cookie Path here. If you want them to be available anywhere on your site, then enter a “/”.

**Cookie Domain.** If you want to enable cookies for a subdomain, enter it here. If you want to enable cookies for all subdomains, enter something like “.domain.com” (make sure there is a “.” before your domain name).

**Use HTTP Only.** To prevent your store from Malware, select “Yes” here. It uses HTTP protocol only and doesn’t allow other protocols such as JavaScript.
Cookie Restriction Mode. You need to select “Yes” here.

Comment: I Have set all the required configuration but in some URLs like https://www.yourdomainname.com/sales/order/history/  the secure cookie is not set.

Comment: but its not working, still domain is not showing secured/HttpOnly flag

Comment: @PraveenNegimani : I am also facing same problem. Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't have specific configuration for this but there is a logic in Session config files. If your secure and unsecure urls are equal (and https of course), magento sets the cookies as secure as OOB.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/Config.php#L210

```php
    $secureURL = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('web/secure/base_url', $this->_scopeType);
        $unsecureURL = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('web/unsecure/base_url', $this->_scopeType);
        $isFullySecuredURL = $secureURL == $unsecureURL;
        $this->setCookieSecure($isFullySecuredURL && $this->_httpRequest->isSecure());
        $this->setCookieSameSite('Lax');
```

So if you set `web/secure/base_url` and `web/unsecure/base_url` same like `https://example.com/` then it'll set your cookies as secure.

**Related Config paths**

Stores > Configuration > (General) > Web > Base URLs (Secure) > Base URL
Stores > Configuration > (General) > Web > Base URLs > Base URL

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer says, for HTTP only, you'll find the option here:

> Stores > Configuration > (General) > Web > Default Cookie Settings

For setting the secure attribute, you can go to the following page and make sure that both the Secure and Unsecure Base URLs are the same and that they both use https://

> Admin > Stores > Configuration > Web

Alternatively, you can also override  setCookieSecure() in Magento\Framework\Session\Config so that it always sets secure as true.

```
class Config extends \Magento\Framework\Session\Config
{
    public function setCookieSecure($cookieSecure)
    {
        $this->setOption('session.cookie_secure', true);
        return $this;
    }
}
```